# How can I union and repartition DataFrames stored in parquet files using fugue?

Tags: fugue

Say I have these 2 parquet files

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame([[0]], columns=["a"]).to_parquet("/tmp/1.parquet")
pd.DataFrame([[0],[2]], columns=["a"]).to_parquet("/tmp/2.parquet")
```

I would like to have a new parquet file that is a row wise union of the two.

The resulting DataFrame should look like this

```
   a
0  0
1  0
2  2
```

I also would like to repartition that new file with a pre-determined number of partitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly solve this problem in either Pandas, Spark or other computing frameworks, but each of them will require different implementations. Using Fugue here, you can have one implementation for different computing backends, more importantly, the logic is unit testable without using any heavy backend.

```
from fugue import FugueWorkflow

def merge_and_save(file1, file2, file3, partition_num):
    dag = FugueWorkflow()
    df1 = dag.load(file1)
    df2 = dag.load(file2)
    df3 = df1.union(df2, distinct=False)
    df3.partition(num=partition_num).save(file3)
    return dag
```

To unit test this logic, just use small local files and use the default execution engine. Assume you have a function `assert_eq`:

```
merge_and_save(f1, f2, f3, 4).run()
assert_eq(pd.read_parquet(f3), expected_df)
```

And in real production, if the input files are large, you can switch to spark

```
merge_and_save(f4, f5, f6, 100).run(spark_session)
```

It's worth to point out that `partition_num` is not respected by the default local execution engine, so we can't assert on the number of output files. But it takes effect when the backend is Spark or Dask.